# Java Android - finding file extension

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio

So I'm trying to get the extension from a file so that I can compare it to a string to see if the extension matches the extension I want to find. However, at the moment I think I am able to get the extension but then comparing it with the one I want to find is causing my app to crash and close immediately. Also, I want it to be able to cope with files that don't have extensions and just pass them off as files that don't match the wanted file extension. Below is the code snippet that performs this, hopefully someone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
File directory =  getFilesDir();
File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();
String[] fileArray;
ListView fileList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fileList);
fileArray = new String[listOfFiles.length];
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; ++i){
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
    if (extension.equals("txt")) {
        fileArray[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
    }
```

P.S: I'm new to Java and Android Development so please be nice to me. :)

EDIT:

Okay, I'm being asked to post my errors, I don't really know how to post them in a nice way but this is the best I can do.

03-29 15:39:32.437 7671-7671/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:39:32.479 7671-7671/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:39:32.522 7671-7671/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:39:32.571 7671-7671/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:39:32.618 7671-7671/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:39:32.671 7671-7671/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:39:32.724 7671-7671/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:39:32.766 7671-7671/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:39:32.809 7671-7671/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:39:32.884 7671-7671/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:39:32.887 7671-7671/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/lib/arm64
03-29 15:39:32.894 7671-7671/? I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.removedforprivacy.appname
03-29 15:39:33.061 7671-7671/? I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
03-29 15:39:33.276 7671-7671/? I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
03-29 15:39:33.349 7671-7727/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-29 15:39:33.396 7671-7671/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
03-29 15:39:34.694 7671-7677/? I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping

The above is the log from when the app is started. This is before the problem area is loaded. The below is when I press the button that triggers the running of the problem area.

03-29 15:42:50.550 10762-10762/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-29 15:42:50.654 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:42:50.808 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:42:50.851 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:42:50.895 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:42:50.953 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:42:51.008 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:42:51.072 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:42:51.151 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:42:51.197 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:42:51.241 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:42:51.315 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.removedforprivacy.appname-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-29 15:42:51.318 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.removedforprivacy.appname-1/lib/arm64
03-29 15:42:51.326 10762-10762/com.removedforprivacy.appname I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.removedforprivacy.appname

One last thing, when I press the button, there is another bit of logs shown which I think is different to the above but it very quickly disappears so I can't copy it in. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you post your crash please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what you mean. No error appears in Android Studio. When the app is running and the page with this code in opens, the app instantly crashes. Sorry, I can't really give you any more.

Comment: click anroid monitor bottom bar android studio and then select error from the drop down menu of Android Monitor to see the error

Comment: Sorry to be awkward, it's rather long, I'm not really sure how much I should put in, plus it's not all that well formatted.

Comment: Check my answer. Accept and upvote if it helps.

Comment: `File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();`. Your variable `listOfFiles` can be null if there are no files found. So check for null before use. And return if it is null. I bet you have a NullPointetException now clearly visible in the logcat.

Comment: If it does not crash any more then do away with the loop to check the extension. Instead you should implement a FileNameFilter.

Comment: Hmm, but I am 100% certain there is a file there right now so I don't think it's this.

Comment: Does not matter. Add the code.

Comment: You posted a lot of non logs. Post the quickly disappearing ones. Freeze them first.

Comment: Also check for extension==null before use.

Comment: Tried extension==null prior to this. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, I think I have made a discovery. As none of the local files have a .txt extension I wondered if as it was trying to update a listView with an empty array, that was causing the error. To test this I added an else clause that just set each file that doesn't have a .txt file extension to "Invalid File". This has worked and the list has been displayed with an entry of "Invalid File". However, I would prefer not to display this message for every file that doesn't match the .txt extension. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Find my solution, MimeTypeMap will not give some proper result. So, do your own method to find the file type from the URL. Check my solution.

```
  public static String getFileType(String fileName) {
    String fileExt = "";
    try {
        if (fileName != null) {
            fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileExt;
}
```

Hopes it will help. Happy Coding

**UPDATE**

See, I think your list file path is string which is URI. so you need to convert into URI . then get the path from that URI. Do the following.

```
   String filePath=String.valueOf(filePath);
   Uri.parse(filePath).getPath();//Here you can get the path of the file which contains the extension of the file.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not worked for me. You see in my code above I reference listOfFiles[i], this is what I'm passing to your function. I've tried passing a getAbsolutePath() version of it and a getName() version but it still crashes I'm afraid. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use ends with to get extension from whole string

```
File directory =  getFilesDir();
File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();
String[] fileArray;

fileArray = new String[listOfFiles.length];
 if (listOfFiles != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; ++i){

             if (listOfFiles[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")){
                          //Do what ever u want

          }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Again, thanks for your answer but the above still results in a crash. :(

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to use `FilenameUtils.getExtension(file_name)` provided by Apache Commons IO. You can add this line to your app's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
}
```

And then use it in your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){
    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
    if (extension.equals("txt")) {
        fileArray[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I wish I could work out what's going on. That doesn't work either I'm afraid. :(

Comment: @BoshJailey Post your error message, so that we can help you.